# What is the best approach to quickly search through a large growing flat file?

Tags: java, file, search, binary, hashmap

I haven't been handed over the details yet, but I am preparing to implement, in Java, a command line search tool to search through a file that contains two fields (docid, orgid).  I have learned that this file started out small and is growing larger all the time.  I need to be able to pass in the docid and get back the orgid.

Can anyone tell me - what might be the best technique for searching a flat file like I have mentioned above?

For right now, we are only dealing with 50,000 lines (over two months) of data in the file but it will grow much quicker once the system is put in place.

It seems like storing this in a binary system that is searchable but I am not sure what all to look into for a start.

I could dump this into a database but that seems like overkill.  Plus to do that I would have to get the database installed on the server and that is going to be difficult.

Comment: Why would it be overkill?

Comment: Will you do the search once in a while, or as a service that is expected to deliver fast answers to multiple queries? In case a) look if you can't use grep, egrep or awk, in the second case, think about a database - for this is exactly why databases have been invented in the first place.

Comment: I would think it would help to provide a few more details. How often are things added and how many are added? Once a day? A few 1000s a day? Continuously, a few every second during daylight? Stuff like that. And then, how many searches are there a day? 10, 1000, 100000?Are the searches for single items or groups? How big might it get? Millions? Billions? what?

Comment: yes, thanks.  Once a month running the main application that will append docid, and orgid to this file for each record (Guessing ~25,000).  After this main app is run my app. will be going back through at least 1% of all of those records and needing to find out what the orgid is based upon the docid.  Ideally, I would want this to be as quick as possible.  The thing is I don't want to introduce 3rd party applications if I can avoid it.  Personally, I don't like how this works out but as I learn more I will try to make a better process.  :-)

Comment: I want to thank everyone for answers/comments. I was talking with another coworker and we talked out the process of serializing and deserializing a hashmap. I had originally thought that the hashmap couldn't handle a large number of elements but I now see that it can. I believe I can manage the sizes of serialized files if necessary. I can serialize the growing data after each monthly run. Then deserialize the file into a hashmap so that I can search for the orgid. thank for suggesting h2 and hsqldb. I did some research on them and I may go with hsqldb if my current idea doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, depending on the size of docid and orgid and the amount of ram you have available to use, you could simply use a hash table.  Read everything into the hash table, and then query against the hash table.  Of course, don't know how many lookups you have to make against this file nor how often this has to be run, and if it needs to be resident in memory or not.

Other options (as previously suggested) are to use a presisted DB.  Most efficient way would be to read the file into the DB and truncate the file so that subsequent reads don't have to reread existing records.  Plus your file remains manageable.  Of course, a lot of questions arise if you try to do that.  Ex: can you truncate the file?  does another process expect the file to exist?  how do you manage race conditions when you attempt to truncate?  etc.

Using something like [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/) or [h2](http://www.h2database.com/) would be great as they could be embedded in your app and you don't have to worry about having them installed independently.  Of course, you need to provide a persistence space for them, or it doesn't do tremendous amount of help.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I ended up working out the server issues and going with hsqldb, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible I would go with inserting data in some database from the beginning (maybe something light like [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/) or [h2](http://www.h2database.com/).

Your data behaves like Map, so maybe something like [mapdb](http://www.mapdb.org/) would be better (but you have to make sure that your  schema is unlikely to change).

If you still need to go with this flat file, maybe Grep is the best idea (it's a fastest tool to search flat files)